# Enabling a text area when value is selected from <select>

Tags: javascript, html

how do i enable a text area when the user select To Be Shipped?

I have these codes.

```
<script>
    function my_func(selectValue){

        if(selectValue=="To Be Shipped") 
        {       
                document.getElementById("trackingNo").disabled="false";
        }
        }
</script>
```

and here is my form.

```
<form action="update_status.php?serial=<?php echo $_GET['serial']?>" method="post">
                    <fieldset>  
                    <h4>Edit Order Status</h4><br>
                    <div id="">
                        <select name="order_status" onchange="my_func(this.value)">
                            <option value="On Process">On Process</option>
                            <option value="Ready for Pickup">Ready for Pickup</option>
                            <option value="To Be Shipped">To Be Shipped</option>
                        </select>                   
                        <label>Tracking Number</label>
                        <input type="text" id="trackingNo" placeholder="Enter Tracking Number" name="tracking_no" disabled>                     
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                    </div> 


                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

how do i fix my codes?

Answer (score 1):

You setting false as string it should be a boolean value like

```
document.getElementById("trackingNo").disabled=false;
```

So your complete function should look like

```
function my_func(selectValue){

    if(selectValue=="To Be Shipped") 
    {       
            document.getElementById("trackingNo").disabled=false;
    }
}
```

There is an alternative solution as suggested by @Ahmed to use removeAttribute function so the syntax would look like

```
document.getElementById("trackingNo").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: You can also `removeAttribute("disabled")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use false as boolean and not as string.

```
document.getElementById("trackingNo").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [JSFiddle.net/siva_hari/9wf5k804](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/9wf5k804/)

```
function my_func(selectValue){
        if(selectValue=="To Be Shipped") 
        {       $("#trackingNo").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    else{
        $('#trackingNo').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has not asked a jquery solution otherwise the tag would have been their

Comment: Updated the solution to use just JavaScript.